# Right Axis not displaying on Dual Axis Grouped Bar and Line Chart D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm working on a Dual Axis group bar and line chart. It's almost completely there. But for some reason, the right axis isn't getting the correct styles or something. Because it's in the svg when I inspect the code, but I can't get it to show up. I've been messing with styling and stuff for about an hour now, and it's probably something really simple. I just haven't been able to find it.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e95u60qv/1/) is a working fiddle with my issue.

Here is the code where it gets applied to the svg:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width) + ",0)")
  .call(YLeftAxis)

  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", -10)

  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Percent");
```

Comment: You need to widen your SVG, which currently doesn't account for margin.right: `.attr("width", width + margin.left)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew said, you don't have enough space in the svg. I made the following changes and now your second axis is displayed correctly:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 100}

var x0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width - margin.right]).padding(0.1);

var XLine = d3.scalePoint().rangeRound([0, width - margin.right]).padding(0.1);
```

[JSFiddle with working axes](https://jsfiddle.net/mozu8kx6/1/)